# Style every 2nd column of asp gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a asp gridview that automatically colors every second row different from every first, which is nice. I also want to do this for the columns (specifically make every first column's content bold(strong) and every 2nd, normal). I know somehow this can be done using css nth-child() but have no idea to go about it with this asp control. Please assist.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the first `<td>` in every row:

```
tr td:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: tr td:nth-child(even)
        {
            font-weight:bolder;
            } was what I used but thank you so much.